# При формировании XML знак амперсанда преобразуется в спецсимвол

Tags: php, xml

Формируется XML документ для карты сайты.

```
$text_loc = $doc->createTextNode( HTTPS_SERVER . "index.php?route=product/category&path=" . $category['category_id'] );
```

Но спецсимвол заменятся кодом.

```
<loc>http://city/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=890</loc>
```

Comment: Да и не только амперсанд

Comment: Потому что со знака амперсанд начинаются имена сущностей (entity). Если его не заменить, то получится сущность `&path`, а её определения нет - в итоге при парсинге будет выброшена ошибка.

Comment: Не волнуйтесь: при парсинге xml вы получите правильный результат. Сущность будет преобразована в нормальный символ. Главное пользоваться парсером, а не регулярками для разбора xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на таблицу специальных символов по ссылке [тут](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

```
Name    Character   Unicode code point (decimal)    Standard    Name
quot    "           U+0022 (34)                     XML 1.0     quotation mark
amp     &           U+0026 (38)                     XML 1.0     ampersand
apos    '           U+0027 (39)                     XML 1.0     apostrophe (1.0: apostrophe-quote)
lt      <           U+003C (60)                     XML 1.0     less-than sign
gt      >           U+003E (62)                     XML 1.0     greater-than sign
```

нет ничего страшного что они заменяются, в обратном преобразовании всё будет хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Просто чтобы дополнить ответ Азиза Умарова. Весь кредит принадлежит ему.

XML имеет пять предопределенных сущностей (entities).

Ссылка на сайт: [Entity References](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)

```
+---------+--------+----------------+
| Entity  | Symbol |  Description   |
+---------+--------+----------------+
| &lt;    | <      | less than      |
| &gt;    | >      | greater than   |
| &amp;   | &      | ampersand      |
| &apos;  | '      | apostrophe     |
| &quot;  | "      | quotation mark |
+---------+--------+----------------+
```